# simple ajax mvc type structure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

How do you go about designing/structuring a completely ajaxed MVCish style site? I guess what confuses me the most is that there would only be one view that adapts and changes to the user actions...

I'm looking to build a really simple app, both front end and back end in this style.

Comment: Only one view? I think that is a dangerous route you are taking (no MVC pun intended)

Comment: I guess I mean one container view, into to which the other views are loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you'd be building a "front controller" of sorts that would route the views (there would be more than one) to the page for rendering in divs.  My company does this with two of its apps and it's lightning fast and a great way to go for a simple app...users love it.  Key to the success is a well-formulated layout with well-defined divs to receive the content.  As you'll be repeatedly writing and re-writing to them, you have to ensure ahead of time that they are able to handle data of various sizes and amounts as you'll have very few ways to effect layout per page on the overall container....besides after-the-fact hacks (just say no!)

Do as you would with controllers and models and the views (the front-end view code)   In some cases our code will use an intermediary page (we call it a mid-model) to generate Jquery data in a JSON string format.  It's not quite a model in that case, as it takes action like a model but sometimes returns more than just JSON depending on the needs of the Jquery element.

An interesting offshoot of this system is the use of a program called [XAJAX](http://www.xajax-project.org/).  It's a PHP library that facilitates AJAX called directly to PHP functions, so it eliminates the need to do intermediary JSON generating pages like Jquery uses.  For those who understand PHP but struggle with Javascript, this can be an easier solution to grasp.  While the documentation hasn't proven very strong, it's a very powerful tool.

Comment: great thanks for the advice, its really helped me think about this. Are your apps public? if so would like to see them in action... XAJAX looks interesting, though im quite new to PHP and more accustomed to JS.

Comment: The applications that extensively use XAJAX and this method are all protected (they power a bank's CRM and several large company's marketing systems) but you can see the very basics on a website I did for a photographer friend at http://www.cakesandkisses.com/gallery_detail.php?id=843#  Let me qualify that I didn't do the UI on that site, but I did build the code that flips the photo when you click on the icons in the lower right and it is using this method and XAJAX specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I would do all your views as usual (except they would only be HTML fragments that would be inserted into the page) and then have an extra "special" controller and view that loads your views via Ajax. When a link is clicked or something like that the JavaScript makes an Ajax request to the special controller with the view you want to load. The special controller then renders the view and sends it back to be inserted into the page.